# Adjectif mélioratif ayant une dimension solennelle ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Je cherche à savoir s'il existe un adjectif positif qui permettrait de parler d'une œuvre d'art classique, quelque chose comme « c'est triste mais c'est bien » (ou vice-versa).

Exemple illustratif : j'ai récemment visionné (et apprécié) deux films très différents : [Bill & Ted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_%26_Ted%27s_Excellent_Adventure) et [Au revoir les enfants](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_revoir_les_enfants).

Pour décrire le premier, pas de problème : c'est un bon film, amusant, distrayant, un peu loufoque, ébouriffant (pour faire '80s)...

Pour le second, en revanche, j'ai plus de mal. C'est sûrement un bon film, peut-être même excellent, fantastique, etc., mais ensuite ? *Puissant* me semble trop viril. *Émouvant* pourrait convenir, mais n'y a-t-il rien de plus fort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peut être ***poignant***:

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poignant):

> 2. Qui suscite une émotion vive, violente. Synon. bouleversant, pathétique, tragique. Regard, récit, spectacle poignant.

Answer (score 2):

*Bouleversant* me semble plus fort qu' *émouvant*. Ou alors, on peut suggérer *ce film m'a pris aux tripes*.